# Alamofire says "Invalid URL" when I add russian letters to the request

Tags: swift, swift3, alamofire

For some reasons I need to make a request string manually:

```
request += "?"
for (key, value) in updatedParameters
{
     request.append("\(key)=\(value)&")
}
```

and then pass it to Alamofire.upload. It works fine unless **value** contains cyrillic letters. Is there any way to encode request string so the request will work?

Comment: @EricAya Looks like it is. What should I do with my question now? Delete?

Comment: No need to delete, it's now marked as a duplicate of the other post - it can be useful for future readers, depending how they search. :)